# When the Kaaba was built, how were people worshiping Allah?

Tags: prophets, kaabah, prophet-ibrahim

I understand that Ibrahim and his son Ismail build the Kaaba but how was worshiping Allah like? I ask this because the Kaaba was built before the Quran and before the rules of the 5 prayers were submitted to people. Did they used to perform Umrah? But doesn't Umrah require the 5 prayers?

Sorry for not knowing about this topic (I am still reading on Islam).
Thank you!

Comment: The Kaaba was not built by Ibrahim and Ismail they only rebuilt it. And it was Ibrahim who called people for Hajj.

Comment: Also see https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27457/what-did-mushrikeen-think-about-who-built-the-kaaba and https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27457/what-did-mushrikeen-think-about-who-built-the-kaaba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In similar ways to how they worship Allah now, the Quran mentions *Tawaf*, which is a major ritual of Hajj and Umrah, and the pillars of Prayer like *Qiyam*, *Sujood* and *Rukuh*:

> وإذ بوأنا لإبراهيم مكان البيت أن لا تشرك بي شيئا وطهر بيتي للطائفين والقائمين والركع السجود
>
> And [mention, O Muhammad], when We designated for Abraham the site of the House, [saying], "Do not associate anything with Me and purify My House for those who perform Tawaf and those who stand [in prayer] and those who bow and prostrate.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 22:26](http://quran.com/22/26)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the construction of the Kaaba, history has shown that Prophet Ibrahim (as) was not the first to build the Kaaba. Rather, the Kaaba was first built in a time when man had not yet been created. That is, before the creation of man, the Kaaba was built by the command of God Almighty and by angels, especially Gabriel (peace be upon him). Of course, the most important purpose of building the Kaaba on earth was that human beings, instead of worshiping idols, stones and wood, worship the one God and praise God Almighty for a single place. In fact, the Kaaba is a symbol of monotheism, and the fact that all people should pray towards the Kaaba is the secret of the unity of Muslims.

Ref: https://www.mashreghnews.ir/news/1098853