# How does Muslims explain revelation of Bible on Jesus?

Tags: prophet-isa, christianity, bible

In Islam, Muslims must believe in the Torah and Injeel, and that they were revealed to Moses and Jesus (Peace be upon them).  But Christians say that Jesus (Peace be upon him) did not receive a book, but was God and was the word, and this is view among the majority of them.

Then how would it be explained to a Christian that the Injeel is in fact a revelation that came to Jesus (peace be upon him) when they say no revelation came to him?

And in what form was it revealed to him? Was it a complete book or bit by bit revelation as was on Muhammad (PBUH)?

Comment: please note the Injil that was revealed is different of the current book which is called Bible which is written many years later.

Comment: @BattleofKarbala yes . I think The bible is the counterpart of hadith, but they do not have any counterpart of Quran. The counterpart of Quran was the Injeel, and the whole of it was not conveyed tho Christians and so it is lost.

Answer (score 3):

God said in [5:110](http://quran.com/5/110) :

> ‘O Jesus, son of Mary, remember My favour to you and to your mother,
>   be thankful for it; when I strengthened you with the Holy Spirit,
>   Gabriel, to speak to people in the cradle and in maturity and when I
>   taught you the Scripture, and wisdom, and the Torah, and the Gospel
>   .....

*(Tafsir al Jalalain)*

Also mentioned in Sura Maryam, [19:29](http://quran.com/19/29): The people asked Mary - `How can we speak to one who is in the cradle a child?`

Jesus suddenly replies, in [19:30](http://quran.com/19/30): `Indeed, I am the servant of Allah . He has given me the Scripture and made me a prophet.`

So Jesus says, when he was still a baby, that God had already given him **the scripture**. Maybe the other three parts mentioned in 5:110, i.e. the wisdom, and the Torah, and **the Gospel**, were revealed in later years.

There is a [gap of about 18 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_years_of_Jesus) in the account of Jesus in the New Testament, so they don't even know what happened to him during those years. How can they claim no revelation came to him?

Whether it was a complete revelation at once or bit-by-bit, we have no source to verify. All we know that he was supported by Gabriel during his whole lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

Hindus say: [Krishan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krishna) was the Avatar of the [Vishnu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishnu) (their God) and there are no prophets and no anything. How would you go and tell him that Krishan was a prophet to the poeple of South Asia (who at that time were Aryans). You give them logics, logics from Quran and Hadees.

Christians don't believe that Jesus (Isa As) was the prophet of Allah, sent to the people of [Bani Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bani_Isra%27il). They believe that the God is the father of Jesus and Jesus is His son, marry being the virgin mother. However at the very same time they do believe there is something known as [Parthenogenesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenogenesis). So, you can't fully make them believe that such thing can and has happened.

Answer to you would be, you can tell him that Allah communicates to His prophets on each and every aspect of life. Teaches them way of living and makes them aware of everything. Those sayings are then saved as the Holy Books for each and every religion. The Holy Book for Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) is Holy Quran, it was revealed in bits it got completed on 27th of Ramadan. Similarly, a whole book with a dark brown binding and a tag name of **Bible** wasn't sent to Jesus, orders and information was sent to jesus bit by bit. And they were collected and made into a hard copy form. Which is known as Injeel.

There are 4 Holy Books that are sent to prophets of Allah:

1. Holy Quran on Holy Prophet Mohammad (PBUH)
2. Injeel on Jesus (Isa As)
3. Taurait on Moses (Musa As)
4. Zabur on David (Daud As)

And yes brother, making someone believe is not as easy as telling them 2+2=4. You cannot force them to believe what you're saying. There is no forcement in religion, Quran states. After all this, Good luck!

Comment: I beg to differ. **1** . Krishan is portrayed as mischievous unlike the prophets  who had humble lives. We cannot say he is a prophet, nor can we deny too **2** Injeel was not written down on a hard copy **3** we have no source to verify Injeel was revealed bit by bit

Comment: 1 Krishan is a prophet of Allah sent to the people of Asia 3000 and some years ago. We believe that, and being a muslim we believe in all 1lac 24thousand prophet, you cannot deny that! 2. Injeel was not written down on a hard copy? Are you crazy? We write stuff in hard copy, there was no soft copy form as there was no computer. -_- 3. That's where it comes that : "No other Holy Book is safe in its initial state, Only Quran is, Because Allah took responsibility to protect its initial state". You do beleive this right? What differ now? :)

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Krishan is prophet of Allah is news to me, interesting. Want to share any related link?

Comment: https://www.alislam.org/library/links/00000158.html .. second link: read the list of prophets section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prophethood_(Ahmadiyya) @muslim1 .. and yes, please try to search for answer and not to just listen to what others have to say. Everyone has its own belief and fate..You must try to do some research around! :)

Comment: injeel was not written down at all. it was as a **Softcopy** in Jesus' mind . There were prophets sent to every nation, but 124,000 exactly ? What's the source?

Comment: So what is the hard copy form? Is it not the real-bible? You're wrong. You're trying to decieve the Jesus and his Holiness. Bible was revealed to jesus in a **Soft Copy** form but only to the Jesus, jesus's decendants wrote it down in **Hard copy** form. That's what I am saying! God never sent down a book, he sent down words to Jesus, which were then forwarded to followers and were written down...@MAKZ

Comment: And yeah sure, here you go: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/298/evidence-of-124-000-prophets-messengers-peace-be-upon-them-in-islam another question on Islam Stack Exchange @MAKZ .. :)

Comment: Hard copy soft copy ... LOL :) these words are not suitable here . By the way the revelation sent to jesus was injeel and unlike Quran, it was not transformed into a book. Just like some Quranic verses are present in Hadith, some of Jesus' knowledge are in the New Testament. But the Injeel as a whole, is lost

Comment: and the [link](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/298/evidence-of-124-000-prophets-messengers-peace-be-upon-them-in-islam) you gave says the hadith is da'if. not saheeh . so the figure 124,000 and the prophethood of krishan is unverifiable

Comment: That's what my point is! The real form of Bible is not present now! There have been changings in it and many or the words have been altered in it...And yes, Quran is the only Holy Book that is available in the real form..

Comment: Salam Alaikum, please do not have lengthy discussion with comments, if you want to discuss please come to our [chat] room.