# Safeguards in place to prevent Imam Mahdi from drone attack?

Tags: imam-mahdi

It believed by all Muslims that the [Mahdi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahdi) will come.  What safeguards will be ensured that it is not bombed down by the US army in a drone attack?

Also in this age of media, a real Mahdi can easily be maligned through toxic propaganda, so how do the Muslims prevent this from happening?

Comment: What is a mahdi ?

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE!  What an unexpected and curious question!

Comment: Could you provide references that ALL muslims believe that mahdi will come?

Comment: @Kilise just click on the link Mahdi that provided in the question. all Muslims believe in Mahdi and we have many Hadith from our prophet that mentioned him and all have accepted about this matter. Muslims have a different idea about his birth. some believe he is alive with a long age and some believe he will be born in the ending time. and the savior is not just for Muslims. Christians also believe in a savior (some believe Jesus will come)

Comment: Not all muslims. There are scholars who doesn't. Here is a video where one eplins this, and also gives examples of other scholars holding this view: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llsqz-rW1QU

Comment: @Kilise could you share the exact moment, it's a long video

Answer (score 1):

Why are you assuming that end of times will be in the present era ... so that the USA, drones and media will be relevant factors? A few centuries back it was the British armed with Gunpowder, more centuries back it was the Mongols and their horses, many more centuries back it was the Roman and Persian Empires armed with swords and arrows. When Muslims themselves were a reckonable force the suspect anti-christ candidates were smaller sects and dissenting groups armed with assassins, troublemakers and heretic beliefs. Maybe Imam Mahdi will come in the distant future when there will be Death-stars and a Galactic empire with a clone army?

Secondly, why are you are assuming that the USA will be on opposing sides to Imam Mahdi? Maybe they will be an ally, Indeed there are some very nice people in the USA, many are more respectful, honest and kind compared to the average populace of some Muslim majority counties.  I am sure that Allah will guide them to choose the right side when the time comes.

To answer your question, the exact time and setting of the 'end of times' has not been revealed to anyone. Whatever enemies and hurdles Islam will face, Allah will make a way.

> *Have they not seen how many a generation before them We have destroyed whom We had established on the earth such as We have not
>   established you? And We poured out on them rain from the sky in
>   abundance, and made the rivers flow under them. Yet We destroyed them
>   for their sins, and We created after them other generations.*  **Quran
>   6:6**

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a very good one, as in how will Mahdi prevail (and basically what attributes should he have to know if he is the true Mahdi)

## Drone:

So God has sent 124000 prophets and all died, killed, poisoned. And he wants to show to everyone that eventually:

*And We wanted to confer favor upon those who were oppressed in the land and make them leaders **and make them inheritors**
[Qasas: 5](https://quran.com/28/5)*

*"Seek help through Allah and be patient. Indeed, the earth belongs to Allah . He causes to inherit it whom He wills of His servants. **And the [best] outcome is for the righteous**."  [Al-A'raf 128](https://quran.com/7/128)*

God has allowed every nation to rule, so each nation shows its true face. There has never been a single nation on planet which can claim their nation was a just nation (except for the nations governed by the prophets). 
Now it is the time for God to show he's above ALL. His nation is just.

And to precisely answer your question:

And we rained down on them a shower (of brimstone): Then see what was the end of those who indulged in sin and crime! [Al-A'raf 84](https://quran.com/7/84)

*And to Allah belong the soldiers of the heavens and the earth. And ever is Allah Exalted in Might and Wise. [Fath 7](https://quran.com/48/7)*

God has control over animals, wind, rain, earth, etc, I did I forget to mention the angels who will aid him (as already done in the battle of Badr)?

*[Remember] when you asked help of your Lord, and He answered you, "Indeed, I will reinforce you with a thousand from the angels, following one another." [Al-Anfal 9](https://quran.com/8/9)*

So a drone could be knocked down by wind, or a terrible rain ( God can create rain of non-water type), tornado, thunderbolt, a good number of birds, angles or other means.

## Media

When the Mahdi comes, his first moment is:

While he has the Ka'ba to his back he will say:

*بَقِيَّتُ اللَّهِ خَيْرٌ لَّكُمْ إِن كُنتُم مُّؤْمِنِينَ*
*What remains [lawful] from Allah is best for you" [Hud 86](https://quran.com/11/86)*

*بقیه الله* is one of the many titles of Mahdi. But when he says such, the **entire world will hear him**—leaving no doubt from anyone. God's media is universal. His message is more visible than the sun. Since it's a non-human act, whatever the media says won't make a difference.
People either believe or not. Either they become humble or not.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the exact number of prophets sent in your answer?

Comment: @Kilise‌ see [here](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/300/13637) but also it's referenced in Bihar al-Anwar Vol.11 Pgs. 28 & 58. But the number isn't really important to this question

Comment: I don't think so , when our prophet pbuh was hurt by his enemies and faced adversities how can Mahdi be safe? , even the Quran does not mention about the kind of supernatural powers of Mahdi which you mentioned .

Comment: I guess he will be having the same limitations and physical powers as a normal human being just like a prophet and may be very few people will actually support him again like a prophet, the rest will be misguided by media propoganda or jealousy because their sect leaders don't approve the Mahdi.

Comment: @Islam good note.His reign is different from the prophet... so they are not to be compared. I did mention verses from Quran where he has aided his believers. About How can he be safe? For Allah it's simple. How did he save Ibrahim from fire? Moses from Pharoah's killing? Same will be applied to Imam Mahdi. As for superpower, Solomon had control over wind. Jesus gave life to the dead. ALL *باذن الله*. The real question is why do you think God can't give such power to a human? Or even give it to an ant? He can give and take at any moment.

Answer (score 0):

In 1965 war, India created a huge bomb apparently to destroy the whole city. And dropped it in Gulberg, which is about 25 kilometers from our home. And because of it's Thud, the glass windows of our house broke. But the bomb never exploded.

Without permission of ALLAH, the bombs cannot go off, the drones can't fly, the fire can't burn.

Comment: So when the Sahabas were martyred by weapons of Mushriks was it by the permission and acceptance of Allah?

Comment: yes indeed. And Sahabas and Muslims consider martyrdom in the way of ALLAH a gift from ALLAH