# What are the source(s) that say that Allah sbwt sent 124000 prophets?

Tags: hadith, history, source-identification, seerah

While watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22EgNJu65vs), I heard aleem [Dr. Omar Zaid](https://zaidpub.com/) mention that Allah sbwt sent a prophet/messenger to every tribe and nation on earth, totaling over 124000. Since he is a notable revert aleem wıth extensive knowledge of previous scriptures as well as Islamic sources, I am sure this statement is based on authentic sources, but as of yet there is no verifiable historical evidence for this.

Which Islamic source(s) assert this?

Comment: See also [is there any evidence in quran or hadith which states taht there were 124000 prophets ...](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/298/is-there-any-evidence-in-quran-or-hadith-which-states-that-there-were-124-000-p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to one Hadith, the Prophet (PBUH) mentions 124,000 (or its roundabouts) prophets before him:

> It was narrated that Abu Dharr said: I said: O Messenger of Allah, how many Prophets were there? He said: “One hundred and twenty four thousand.” I said: O Messenger of Allah, how many of them were Messengers? He said: “Three hundred and thirteen, a good number.” I said: O Messenger of Allah, who was the first of them? He said: “Adam.” …
>
> Narrated by Ibn Hibbaan, 361

However, since no mention of an ‘exact’ number of Prophets has been mentioned in the “Sahih Hadith” meaning those of the great Imams: Bukhari, or Muslim, or Tirmidhi, or Abu Dawood, or Ibn Maajah, the authenticity of the above-mentioned Hadith is considered da’eef.

However, the Glorious Quran mentions specific names of the Prophets:

> “Verily, We have inspired you (O Muhammad SAW) as We inspired Nooh (Noah) and the Prophets after him; We (also) inspired Ibrahim (Abraham), Ismail (Ishmael), Ishaque (Isaac), Yaqoob (Jacob), and Al-Asbat (the twelve sons of Yaqoob (Jacob)), Iesa (Jesus), Ayub (Job), Yoonus (Jonah), Haroon (Aaron), and Sulaiman (Solomon), and to Dawood (David) We gave the Zaboor (Psalms).
>
> And Messengers We have mentioned to you before, and Messengers We have not mentioned to you, - and to Moosa (Moses) Allah spoke directly”
>
> [an-Nisa’ 4:163-164].

The tafsir of Ibn Kathir has the following to say on these verses:
Ibn Katheer (may Allah have mercy on him) said:

> These are the names of the Prophets whose names are mentioned in the Qur’an: Adam, Idrees, Nooh, Hood, Saalih, Ibraaheem, Loot, Ismaa‘eel, Ishaaq, Ya‘qoob, Yoosuf, Ayyoob, Shu‘ayb, Moosa, Haroon, Yoonus, Dawood, Sulaymaan, Ilyaas, al-Yasa‘, Zakariya, Yahya, and ‘Eesa (blessings and peace be upon them), as well as Dhu’l-Kifl according to many commentators, and their leader is Muhammad (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him).
> The words “and Messengers We have not mentioned to you” mean: other people who are not mentioned in the Qur’an.
>
> Tafseer Ibn Katheer, 2/469

However it is the belief of every single Muslim that Our Prophet (PBUH) was final messenger and prophet of Allah Almighty, the Seal of Prophethood, and the Sealed Nectar of humanity itself.

May Allah Almighty allow us to be on the true path Insha ‘Allah & summa Ameen.